# FB like button - page not found

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

FB like button gaves me "page not found" on page where actually user is...

It's on this page down
http://www.lifeinsuitcase.com/adventures/going-to-dublin

When you just hover on like you will see (I am not here for likes).

There was old version 2.4 of FB SDK. So I've tried to update it with documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button but error still occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried fb object debugger and turns out, that og:title is missing, so after I add it it works. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Also it can be problem with some fb cache (which is also solved by fetching new informations from object debugger)